# Omitting "Case" from "Select...Case" Statement

Tags: vb.net, syntax

This isn't really a problem, but more of a curiosity of mine that I haven't been able to resolve by my own means. I surely won't be losing any sleep over it.

In VB.NET, the switch statement syntax is (as documented on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)):

```
Select [ Case ] testexpression
[ Case expressionlist
    [ statements ] ]
[ Case Else
    [ elsestatements ] ]
End Select
```

Note that in the first line, `Case` is in square brackets, meaning that it is optional.

And indeed, the following example compiles and executes in the same way as if the `Case` keyword had been included, at least, in the rudimentary examples I've tried:

```
Select myIntVar
    Case 0
        Return "Nothing"
    Case 1
        Return "Just one"
    Case Else
        Return "Something else"
End Select
```

Therefore my question is as follows:
Aside from syntax, is there *any* difference between opening a switch statement with `Select` and `Select Case`?

Comment: None that I can think of. If `MSDN` does not mention anything one could assume it does not. I hate to assume...

Comment: interesting question, I bet that "CASE" is optional since it seems to line up with a C# switch statement without it anyways (Perhaps the "CASE" portion is just a carryover from old vb), and that it probably compiles to the same either way in CLR

Comment: Another interesting aspect is that even though, according to the MSDN, the `Case` is optional, if you leave it out, Visual Studio automatically adds it for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did a small experiment. I made up a small console application like so:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim myStr As String = GetString(1)
    End Sub

    Private Function GetString(myIntVar) As String
        Select myIntVar
            Case 0
                Return "Nothing"
            Case 1
                Return "Just one"
            Case Else
                Return "Something else"
        End Select
    End Function

End Module
```

The first run was as pictured above, and then I compiled it again inserting the `Case` keyword. I disassembled both created executables using `ILDasm` and pasted the IL of the `GetString` function into this online diff site: http://www.diffchecker.com/9ef7z423

Looks to me like `Select Case` and plain old `Select` are purely syntax differences (this is of course excluding the usage of `Select` in LINQ queries).

Comment: Of course, if you were missing some subtle nuance about the language (I don't think you are, as my answer indicates), you might have compiled in one circumstance where the nuance wasn't exposed. I.e. if it **did** make a difference, it could be some edge case that your example doesn't use.

Comment: Programmatically, VB.Net automatically adds the 'Case' for you on run. So definitely you'll have the same response.

Answer (score 2):

I would say there is **no** difference between the two forms. However, my only evidence is by way of an absence of drawing any distinction. Rather than looking at the Language Reference, the definitive place to look is in the [Language *Specification*](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=15039)<sup>1</sup>.

In Version 11, under section 10.8.2, the Select Case statement is discussed, and the syntax shown is:

> *SelectStatement*  ::=
>     `Select`  [  `Case`  ]  *Expression*  *StatementTerminator*
>     [  *CaseStatement*+  ]
>     [  *CaseElseStatement*  ]
>     `End  Select`  *StatementTerminator*

So, it's clear that this section does cover both forms. However, in the preceding 5 paragraphs (the entirety of the specification for Select Case Statements) no distinction is drawn between the two forms.

<sup>1</sup>The Reference tries to be descriptive, give examples, and uses (at times) looser language. The Specification should be followable to create a Visual Basic compiler. If something is missing from the former, then it may just be an omission. If something is missing from the latter, then it's not officially part of the language.

Answer (score 1):

I think this comes from VB 6.0 where `Select Case` was mandatory - `Select` wasn't a statement on its own. This would mean that it's now just down to personal preference in VB.NET.

**Edit**: Strangely, if you do choose to omit it, Visual Studio will add it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just a difference in syntax, in terms of between languages, such as VB and C#

a switch statement requires the keyword break in order to break out of the loop.

Can't think of anything major, in terms of differences... sorry.